# How to Order An Array Of Data and Display It In That Order (Data On Firebase)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a project where I want to display badges (an image with a title) in a horizontal scroll view. The data for the badges is stored in a Firestore database. My code can fetch the data and show the badges in a horizontal scroll view. At the moment the badges are in a random order and I want to be able to sort them so they are in the correct order. For example:

Currently I have 4 badges, These include:

10k steps badge, 20k steps badge, 30k steps badge, 40k steps badge

This is the order I want them to be displayed in the horizontal scrollview however they are in a random order.

How can I order this data correctly? I am currently using a ForEach to Loop through the data.

My Model for the badges is as follows:

```
struct FitnessBadge: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var fitness_badge_name: String
    var fitness_badge_details: String
    var fitness_badge_image: String
    
}
```

The View for the Badges is as follows:

```
struct FitnessBadgeView: View {
    
    var fitnessBadge: FitnessBadge
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .center){
            
            // Downloading Image From Web...
            WebImage(url: URL(string: fitnessBadge.fitness_badge_image))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(15)
            
            HStack(spacing: 8){
                
                Text(fitnessBadge.fitness_badge_name)
                    
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            HStack(alignment: .center){
                
                Text(fitnessBadge.fitness_badge_details)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(2)

                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

How the badges are being displayed in a scroll view is as follows:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    
    Text("Fitness Badges")
            .font(.title2)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            
    HStack(spacing: 10){
        
        ForEach(AchievementPageModel.filteredFitnessBadges){fitnessBadge in
            
            // Badge View...
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top), content: {
                
                FitnessBadgeView(fitnessBadge: fitnessBadge)
                
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[image: This is the horizontal scroll view]

I want it to go: 10k steps, 20k steps, 30k steps etc.

The AchievementPageModel.filteredFitnessBadges array is as follows:

```
class AchievementPageViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
 
    // Fitness Badges Data...
    @Published var fitnessBadges: [FitnessBadge] = []
    
    @Published var filteredFitnessBadges: [FitnessBadge] = []
    
}
```

And the fetching data for the badges is as follows:

```
func fetchFitnessBadgeData(){
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("FitnessBadges").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
        
        guard let fitnessBadgeData = snap else{return}
        
        self.fitnessBadges = fitnessBadgeData.documents.compactMap({ (doc) -> FitnessBadge? in
            
            let id = doc.documentID
            let name = doc.get("fitness_badge_name") as! String
            let image = doc.get("fitness_badge_image") as! String
            let details = doc.get("fitness_badge_details") as! String
            
            return FitnessBadge(id: id, fitness_badge_name: name, fitness_badge_details: details, fitness_badge_image: image)
        })
        
        self.filteredFitnessBadges = self.fitnessBadges
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is `AchievementPageModel.filteredFitnessBadges`? Knowing how you created this array would help, that's what you need to sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a terrific answer by @HunterLion but it could become impractical and not scaleable because it assumes you're loading ALL of the documents from `FitnessBadges` into memory (an array) to allow for sorting.

What if there are 1 million documents? That could be a LOT of data and overwhelm the device.

Another option is to let Firestore do the heavy lifting; instead of sorting on your app, let Firestore do it!

With larger amounts of data, you will be *way* better off allowing Firebase to sort on the server and present that sorted data to your app because then you can read smaller 'chunks' of data through pagination.

A better solution would be to use `order(by:` like this

```
db.collection("FitnessBadges").order(by: "fitness_badge_name").getDocuments
```

That sorts millions of documents in a flash on the server and then you can get just the section you want - records 1-10 for example, and then 11-20 and they will be sorted.

For reference: [Firestore Pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

Answer (score 2):

In the view where badges are being displayed, replace:

```
ForEach(AchievementPageModel.filteredFitnessBadges)
```

with:

```
ForEach(AchievementPageModel.filteredFitnessBadges.sorted { $0.fitness_badge_name < $1.fitness_badge_name })
```

This will sort by the field `fitness_badge_name`. I have assumed that's the field that contains "10k", "20k"... if the key is another field, just replace the variable in the `.sorted()` function.

Comment: Good answer! Gave you an upvote - see my optional answer for another take on it.